# Configuring Xbuntu 16.04 and external monitor names

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, xfce, 16.04, xfce-panel

I'm using a laptop  - sometimes alone, sometimes with an external monitor placed on the right side and sometimes two monitors, where one is on the left, and the other on right of the laptop's display. I would like to put Xfce panels always on LVDS (not on external monitor).

In Xubuntu 14.04 I did this using:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-0/output-name -s LVDS1
```

After upgrading to a new LTS - Xubuntu 16.04 - this doesn't work anymore. In that place is expected name like `monitor-0`, `monitor-1` etc - counted from left - so LVDS is visible as `monitor-0` or `monitor-1` depending on its configuration.

Is there any way to revert previous(from 14.04) behaviour, where names from `xrandr` (like LVDS/DP-X) are expected by `xfconf`? Or any other way to place Xfce panels always on a specific physical monitor?

Comment: i've found, that it's connected with changes described in https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10725 - but... maybe there is any workaround...?

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "I would like to put xfce panels always on LVDS." ??? Does it mean: I would like to use LVDS to control and manage my external monitor resolution? Panels = screens=monitors? This is an issue with a hardware resource name?

Comment: LVDS1 - internal monitor of my laptop. DP1 - monitor connected by first DisplayPort connector etc - this are names visible in xrandr tool. I would like to have panel (object on xfce - http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start) visible always on internal monitor of laptop, independly if there are any other monitors connected via displayport/vga/hdmi etc.

Comment: I vote for reopening question. First - it's not a bug - it's a feature. Changing was planned. Only - it a bit disturb me. Second - now 16.04 is a stable version, not deveopment anymore ;)